# Eclipse, Interpretation Gitlab Arrows in Package Explorer

Tags: eclipse, gitlab, package-explorer

I was googling about of Gitlab on Eclipse about what means this image:

[image]

Secondary click doesn't say nothing about this.

I need to be secure about the changes using Eclipse

https://www.google.com/search?q=arrow+upload++%22package+explorer%22+Eclipse+Gitlab&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiV8bbsn9_YAhXFkpAKHW_bBKMQ_AUICSgA&biw=1359&bih=656&dpr=1

At least if you have some inditication, when the Mouse is over the package or folder selected the Eclipse must to show a caption or message indicating what is recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This arrow indicates that you have committed once (therefore the one), but you haven't pushed the changes to your `remote` yet. The `remote` would be in your case Gitlab.

[EGit/User Guide - Label Decorations](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Label_Decorations):

> ↑N – The local branch has N commits that are not yet on the remote-tracking branch. This can be read as "N commits to push".